# Generic query to get records from different tables

Tags: c#

In our project we connecting to database with Linq-to-Entities. To read valid records from ,let's say, table1 there is method:

```
public List<tableName> GetTableNameRecords()
{
try
{
    return (from x in _context.tableName
                      where x.valid == 1
                      select x).ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
}
```

It works, but there is a problem - for each table we need to write the same query and only change table name. Is there a way to write generic method where we could only pass table name? Something like:

```
public List<T> GetRecords<T>()
{
try
{
    return (from x in _context.<T>
                      where x.valid == 1
                      select x).ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: To achieve this you must change your context class. In real world the are not table names, they are properties in your context class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection for this, but you're facing some rather ugly code. However, if you're willing to change your models a little bit, you can do that in a relatively straightforward way.

Create an interface that has one property - `valid`, like so:

```
interface IValid
{
    bool valid { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure all your models that have this valid field implement the interface. Then you can do something like this:

```
List<T> GetValid<T>(DbContext context) where T: IValid
{
    return context.Set<T>().Where(x=>x.valid).ToList()
}
```

By having your models implement the interface, you can use an ordinary LINQ expression and have the compiler sort everything out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension that uses reflection

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetRecords<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        //check property exists
        var temp = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { });
        if (temp.GetType().GetProperty("valid") == null)
            return source;

        return (from item in source
                let table = item.GetType()
                let property = table.GetProperty("valid")
                let value = property.GetValue(item, null)
                where (int)value == 1
                select item).ToList();
    }
```

call it with something like

```
 int count = _context.TableName.GetRecords().Count();
```